# installing the foundation icon fonts into laravel

Tags: laravel-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to figure out how to install all the foundation icon sets into my laravel app

the [documentation](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3) is pretty unclear imo

my folder structure right now before trying to add any of the icon fonts is this.

```
www
-app
--assets
---img
---js
---sass
----foundation
-----components
-----_functions.scss
-----_settings.scss
-----app.scss
-----foundation.scss
-----normalize.scss
-public
--css
---foundation
---app.css
---foundation.css
---jquery-ui.css
---normalize.css
--img
--js
```

The icon sets to be added are foundation_icons_accessibility, foundation_icons_general, foundation_icons_general_enclosed and foundation_icons_social

Can someone tell me were each component for each font goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icon fonts such as "Foundation Icons" and "Font Awesome" are front end assets. This means they are related to the UI of your application and not the core logic or "back-end".

Simply create a new folder called "fonts" under your public directory and place all your font files in there. Be sure to change the references in your CSS files to accommodate this change in the font file location.

```
www
-app
--assets
---img
---js
---sass
----foundation
-----components
-----_functions.scss
-----_settings.scss
-----app.scss
-----foundation.scss
-----normalize.scss
-public
--css
---foundation
---app.css
---foundation.css
---jquery-ui.css
---normalize.css
---foundation-icons.css
--fonts
---foundation-icons.ttf
---foundation-icons.woff
---foundation-icons.svg
---foundation-icons.eot
--img
--js
```

Comment: This is the beauty of Laravel, it gives you the ability to structure your application in anyway you wish. Make as many folders and sub-folders as you want...

Comment: Thanks that does help somewhat but its really what to do with the css / scss files that is causing me the trouble.  I have copied all the scss to app/assets/sass/foundation and updated the _settings.scss file and app.scss file as directed but it hasnt worked so I am guessing there are paths in there that need to be changed but I dont know were they are.

Comment: also should the path in scss be relative to the root of the public folder or to the root of the css folder?

Comment: Having similar issue...